# Automatically update shared calendars

Tags: macos, calendar

My wife and daughter share calendars with me.

However every time they update an entry I am prompted to allow the entry.

Is there any way to allow this to happen without interaction - I just want to know what they are doing so my appointments don't clash.

Example -

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Thinkr - It's not a refresh issue, it's a 'you have a new calendar entry, open this then click OK' which I've never found any way to avoid, iOS or macOS, you have to OK it on one or the other.

Comment: iOS has a "Shared Events > Show Changes" toggle for "Display messages when shared events on this calendar are added, modified, or deleted by other people." This toggle isn't available on macOS Calendar unfortunately.